# Why dont the try catch statements work in TwinCAT 4024.7

Tags: try-catch, twincat

I'm trying the newly implemented try/catch statements which are available since TwinCAT 4024.0. However, I'm getting the following error when compiling:

> The codegenerator for the current device does not support structured exception handling.

Example code ([source](https://stefanhenneken.wordpress.com/2019/07/29/iec-61131-3-exception-handling-with-__try-__catch/)):

```
FUNCTION F_Calc : LREAL
VAR_INPUT
  pData     : POINTER TO ARRAY [0..9] OF LREAL;
  nElementA : INT;
  nElementB : INT;
END_VAR
VAR
  exc       : __SYSTEM.ExceptionCode;
END_VAR

__TRY
  F_Calc := pData^[nElementA] / pData^[nElementB];
__CATCH (exc)
  IF (exc = __SYSTEM.ExceptionCode.RTSEXCPT_ARRAYBOUNDS) THEN
    F_Calc := -1;
  ELSIF ((exc = __SYSTEM.ExceptionCode.RTSEXCPT_FPU_DIVIDEBYZERO) OR
         (exc = __SYSTEM.ExceptionCode.RTSEXCPT_DIVIDEBYZERO)) THEN
    F_Calc := -2;
  ELSIF (exc = __SYSTEM.ExceptionCode.RTSEXCPT_ACCESS_VIOLATION) THEN
    F_Calc := -3;
  ELSE
    F_Calc := -4;
  END_IF
__ENDTRY
```

Comment: Adding this Q&A because Google doesn't show any results when searching for the error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the try catch statements are not supported for 64-bit systems yet. This is also mentioned in [this](https://stefanhenneken.wordpress.com/2019/07/29/iec-61131-3-exception-handling-with-__try-__catch/) article.

From the comment section of this article on why it doesn't work on 64-bit yet:

> In the case of an exception, quite a lot happens internally. For
>   example, the stack must be cleaned. Especially with deeply nested
>   method calls, this can mean a lot of work. I suspect that memory
>   management is structured under 32 bit differently than under 64 bits.
>   However, I assume that this will be implemented for 64 bit systems in
>   a later build.