# Throw Exceptions in CODESYS

Tags: exception, codesys

How can I throw standard system exceptions (and if possible, create custom exceptions and throw them too).

The simplest thing that comes to mind, is to just divide a variable by zero, but that's just a hack at best.

I did find mentions of a function `AppGenerateException` in the `CmpApp` library, but I can't find any documentation for it, nor any examples. Can anybody point me to some documentation for this?

Comment: Can you tell a little more what you are trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is completely different approach to solve your task.

Comment: @Sergey Romanov, as I said, in CODESYS we have `__TRY`, `__CATCH` and `__FINALLY` to catch `EXCEPTION`s thrown by standard functions. How can I do the same. And if possible, can I define custom exceptions and use them?

Comment: The try, catch etc. in codesys are for detecting system exceptions like dividing by zero and so on. I agree with Sergey, there are million other ways to achieve this probably in a better way.

Comment: I added one answer. But I still think that Sergey is right.

Comment: @Quirzo, I won't deny that there might be a better way, however, I come from a OOP (Object Oriented Programming) background such as C#, JAVA and KOTLIN, where throwing and handling exceptions is a core mechanic in my opinion. Besides, I just want to know whether it is possible, and to use it or not, and what is better is a subjective preference.

Comment: @Guiorgy it is absolutely not right to try to apply programming patterns styles and approaches of C-like language to ST. It is like you give me the bottle and I'll ask where is the handle, and argument it because I come from background of using cup. In different language different tasks solved differently. As I've said, tell what you want to do and perhaps there is an elegant way to do that, rather than trying to ally technic that was never meant for this language.

Comment: @Serget Romanow, more and more elements of OOP are being added into IEC 61131, so clearly that's a direction that things are moving. However, as I have said, I do agree that there can be better solutions, but which to choose is left to individual (and team, others beside me like OOP too) preference. I wanted to know how to solve my problem through this method, if at all possible. As for why I wanted this, please read my comment to Quirzo's Answer, and if you think there's a better approach to the problem, by all means, please do tell, I am new to PLC programming and appreciate any help! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity I checked the `AppGenerateException` and got it working. Got some help from [this Codesys help page](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_obj_pou_checkbounds/).

**I still think this is not the best way to achieve what you need, but it could work.**

Unfortunately, I have 64 bit system and the TRY..CATCH is not yet working in other that 32 bit systems as far as I know, so I couldn't test catching.

Add the following libraries:

- CmpApp
- SysExcept

Then the following code seems to work. Set `ThrowErr` to true to get the system exception.

```
PROGRAM PRG_TestThrow
VAR CONSTANT
    MY_PRIVATE_EXCEPTION : DWORD := 32001;
END_VAR
VAR
    ThrowErr    : BOOL; //Set this to TRUE to throw an error

    //The next two are for getting App instance
    _pApp       : POINTER TO CmpApp.APPLICATION;
    _Result     : SysExcept.SysTypes.RTS_IEC_RESULT;
END_VAR



//Get App instance
_pApp := AppGetCurrent(pResult := ADR(_Result));

IF ThrowErr THEN
    ThrowErr := FALSE;

    IF _pApp <> 0 THEN
        //Throw divide by zero exception
        AppGenerateException(pApp:=_pApp,   ulException:=RtsExceptions.RTSEXCPT_DIVIDEBYZERO);

        //You could use probably any available number as your own custom exception. 
        //For example the following works BUT not sure if it's ok to this.
        //AppGenerateException(pApp:=_pApp,   ulException:=MY_PRIVATE_EXCEPTION);

        //See RtsExceptions type for available exception codes. 
        //For my Codesys version, it has largest exception number of 0x2000 so all larger number are free (for now...)
    END_IF
END_IF
```

It seems that it's possibly to use any custom exception code like:

```
AppGenerateException(pApp:=_pApp,   ulException:=MY_PRIVATE_EXCEPTION);
```

But it's not documented so I would be careful.

Comment: @Quizon, thanks for the answer, I'll try it shortly when I can. Just to be sure, about the try catch not working with x64, is that documented anywhere? Also if you don't mind, when you say there are better ways, can you give me a few suggestions? No need to go in depth, just some links for further reading would be appreciated as well!

Comment: I actually can't find any documentation for Codesys. For TwinCAT it is [documented somehow](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/36028799548151179.html&id=269182850999369499) and it has asked [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521446/why-dont-the-try-catch-statements-work-in-twincat-4024-7). I get similar error message when I try to use it. The biggest reason not to use this is that if you forgot to catch an error, the PLC will stop immediately. That can be quite harmful in PLC world. Also the support seems quite bad.

Comment: And to add: I would use methods, outputs or properties of function blocks like `IsError`, `GetError` to get error information. Function block error outputs are quite used in PLC coding so other programmers would know immediately what is going on. But if you want to use the TRY..CATCH, I would create a function like `Throw` that does the magic and uses your own error codes defined somewhere.

Comment: thanks for the great response. I don't intend to use exceptions for runtime (at least for now), my main scenario is like so: Suppose I have a function that takes an ENUMERATOR as an input, but in this case I only accept part of it's values as valid. My wish is to prevent someone using my function from ever passing such value by throwing an exception that will stop their run and display an error in the logs. Ideally I would love to pass a message with the exception/error, not sure if that's possible though? Would you consider throwing an exception a good solution in such case?

Comment: If you use it yourself or if you document it **very** well, it could be ok. But think of a scenario that somebody uses your block but doesn't know about that. There is a machine running and the PLC passes a wrong value to that block and then an exception is thrown. But the user didn't know about exceptions so there is no try..catch and the PLC will stop as well as the machine. That could be quite bad situation. Perhaps a better solution would be something like a `valid` named output, that will be true if the calculation is ok and the return value can be used?

Comment: an interesting proposition. I have every intention to fully document my code, but I think I'll bring the two options to the others and decide with them the better choice for us. Either way, thank you for your time!